# Swift Custom Annotation does not get select

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a custom annotationView on my map, when I select the custom annotation i want to create a action and pass the annotation data to another view. The best way for it to work I would have to use the built in func `didSelect`. When i do select the custom annotation nothing thing happen. Im not show why the `didSelect` function did not get called thank you in advance.

```
   class RquestCustomPointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation {
    var image: String!
}

func placeRquestByUsersOnMap(){
        //retrieve item from firebase
        var markerArray = [MKPointAnnotation]()
        let path = "rquest/frontEnd/posts/userCreatedPost"

        self.childRef(path).observe(.childAdded, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith: {snapshot, _ in
            //get status
            if let status = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? String {
                if status == "pending"{
                    let indentifier = "rquest"
                    if let coordinate = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "coordinate").value as? NSDictionary {
                        let lat = coordinate["lat"] as! Double
                        let long = coordinate["long"] as! Double
                        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
                        let point = RquestCustomPointAnnotation()
                        let rquestView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: point, reuseIdentifier: indentifier)
                        point.image = "22"

                        let key = snapshot.key
                        point.coordinate = location
                        point.accessibilityValue = key
                        point.accessibilityLabel = "Rquest"
                        markerArray.append(point)

                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(rquestView.annotation!)

                        //create an obserarver to check if it is
                        let paths = "rquest/frontEnd/posts/userCreatedPost/\(key)/"
                        self.childRef(paths).observe(.childChanged, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith: { (snap, _) in
                            if snap.key == "status" {
                                if let status = snap.value as? String {
                                    if status != "pending" {
                                        for i in markerArray {
                                            if i.accessibilityValue == key {
                                                self.mapView.removeAnnotation(i)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
 if annotation is RquestCustomPointAnnotation {
            let reuseIdentifier = "rquest"
            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

            if annotationView == nil {
                annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
                annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            } else {
                annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            }

            let customPointAnnotation = annotation as! RquestCustomPointAnnotation
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: customPointAnnotation.image)


            return annotationView
        }

}


 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

     print("did select")

    }
```

Comment: Whenever i do not use custom annotation it work but when I use custom annotation it does not work. I can add a target to the custom annotation but I need to use the annotation data so addTarget will not be good.

Comment: @Rob I added more code to help solve it

Comment: @Rob by adding a title to the to the annotation did activate the `didSelect` function. I will remove the extra annotations from `placeRquestByUsersOnMap` Thank you for the help. If you submit an answer I can accept it so you can get the points points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `canShowCallout` set to `true`. So, when you tap on it, do you want callout or have it call `didSelect`? (Usually you'd do one or the other, but not both.) And are you seeing your callout?

I notice a curious behavior that if (a) the annotation doesn't have a `title`, and (b) the annotation view's `canShowCallout` is `true`, then not only can it not show the callout, but it also prevents the `didSelect` from being called.

You may either want to turn `canShowCallout` to `false`, or make sure your annotation has a `title`.